# Ettercap duplicate traffic

Tags: debian, tcp, arp-poisoning

I have a ARM device(Guruplug) and i want it to perform an ARP spoofing attack on the network.
This device has 2 ethernet interfaces and 1 Wireless acces point.

I want to plug this device in a network, let it perform an ARP spoofing Attack, become the man in the middle and then send all the traffic over the wireless acces point to my laptop and run a wireshark session on my laptop and see all the traffic off the wired network.

Here a litte scheme :

```
pc--------|----- |
          |      |                    -----------------
pc--------|SWITCH|-------------------|Default Gateway|
          |      |                    -----------------
pc--------|----- |
            | |
            | |
 (eth0)     | |
ARM---------  |
Device-------
 v     (eth1: duplicate packets from eth0, going to the right destination)
 V(uap0:duplicate packets from eth0)
 v
Laptop (running wireshark, sees every packet)
```

now i don't know how to do this. with the tee command off ip tables i can only duplicate UDP traffic, but i also want TCP. I can poison the arp and sniff the traffic on the device itself with ettercap but that is terminal only, and i want to see it live on my laptop.

If it matters, the ARM device is running Debian (Lenny) and my laptop Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04

I'm not asking for a how to, because i'm sure i'm not getting that ;)
but some hints to some good articles or software would be nice! :)

Thanks in Advance!